# centos 6 permissions issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, centos

I have a dedicated server with Centos6 and cPanel, all I want is to install Magento 2 on this server. My problem is with files and folders permissions. in the Magento 2 documentation I need to set this permissions find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; && chmod u+x bin/magento . when I set this permision to my home/username/public_html I get this error in browser.

**Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.**

is anyone who can point me in one direction to solve this?
thank you

```
**Output**

    **ls -al /path/to/magento**

drwxr-x---. 13 nobody nobody     4096 Jan 29 18:30 ./
drwx--x--x. 10 quick  quick      4096 Jan 29 18:29 ../
drwxr-xr-x.  4 nobody root       4096 Jan 29 18:30 app/
drwxr-xr-x.  2 nobody root       4096 Jan 29 18:30 bin/
drwxr-xr-x.  2 nobody quick      4096 Jan 29 18:28 cgi-bin/
-rw-r--r--.  1 nobody root     437404 Jan 28 04:12 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r--.  1 nobody root       1851 Jan 28 04:10 composer.json
-rw-r--r--.  1 nobody root     315984 Jan 28 04:12 composer.lock
-rw-r--r--.  1 nobody root       3425 Jan 28 04:12 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-r--r--.  1 nobody root      10011 Jan 28 04:12 CONTRIBUTOR_LICENSE_AGREEMENT.html
-rw-r--r--.  1 nobody root        631 Jan 28 04:12 COPYING.txt
drwxr-xr-x.  4 nobody root       4096 Jan 29 18:30 dev/
-rw-r--r--.  1 nobody root       1032 Jan 28 04:10 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--.  1 nobody root       2918 Jan 28 04:12 Gruntfile.js
-rw-r--r--.  1 nobody root       7592 Jan 28 04:12 .htaccess
-rw-r--r--.  1 nobody root       6419 Jan 28 04:12 .htaccess.sample
-rw-r--r--.  1 nobody root       1358 Jan 28 04:12 index.php
drwxr-xr-x.  4 nobody root       4096 Jan 29 18:30 lib/
-rw-r--r--.  1 nobody root      10374 Jan 28 04:12 LICENSE_AFL.txt
-rw-r--r--.  1 nobody root      10364 Jan 28 04:12 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r--.  1 nobody quick  35749362 Jan 29 18:29 Magento-CE-2.0.2-2016-01-28-02-26-45.tar.bz2
-rw-r--r--.  1 nobody root       4108 Jan 28 04:12 nginx.conf.sample
-rw-r--r--.  1 nobody root       1427 Jan 28 04:12 package.json
-rw-r--r--.  1 nobody root       1659 Jan 28 04:12 .php_cs
-rw-r--r--.  1 nobody root        804 Jan 28 04:12 php.ini.sample
drwxr-xr-x.  2 nobody root       4096 Jan 29 18:30 phpserver/
drwxr-xr-x.  6 nobody root       4096 Jan 29 18:30 pub/
-rw-r--r--.  1 nobody root       4388 Jan 28 04:10 README.md
drwxr-xr-x.  7 nobody root       4096 Jan 29 18:30 setup/
-rw-r--r--.  1 nobody root       3731 Jan 28 04:12 .travis.yml
drwxr-xr-x.  8 nobody root       4096 Jan 29 18:30 update/
drwxr-xr-x.  2 nobody root       4096 Jan 29 18:30 var/
drwxr-xr-x. 27 nobody root       4096 Jan 29 18:30 vendor/


    **ps -ef | grep httpd**
root     14165     1  0 11:43 ?        00:00:01 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   18801 14165  0 18:35 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   18802 14165  0 18:35 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   18803 14165  0 18:35 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   18804 14165  0 18:35 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   18805 14165  0 18:35 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
root     18975 20796  0 18:43 pts/0    00:00:00 grep httpd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also probably need to `chwon user:group bin/magento` on the files you have installed (the magento files).  You need to figure out which user Apache is running as and change `user:group` above to that, something like `apache:apache` or whatever is in your httpd.conf file.

Post some more info (`ls -al /path/to/magento` and `ps -ef | grep httpd` for apache), but I'll bet that's your problem.

**Edit**

Based on your edited output, you need to chown the files to be owned by `nobody`, which is the user apache is running as.  This can be done via `chown -R nobody /path/to/magento`

Note that you only show the `.bz2` archive, but you need to chown the **extracted** files.

Also, you said you had to use the user that cpanel created when you installed it, so there you go.

Comment: Good god man, edit your post and put the output in there formatted, I can't read that!

Comment: ok i extract that arhive and then i use chown -R nobody /path/to/magento is still the same

Comment: after i use the command i can;t connect to ftp client, something about insuficient permissions

Comment: You didn't really run `chown -R nobody /path/to/magento` did you?  You don't literally type the `/path/to/magento`, it needs to be the real path on your install.

Comment: i use with my path, i will add the output please take a look now

Comment: and is no file in var/log/http

Comment: if i change nobody with quick the username that was created by cPanel the files are there

Comment: OK, so you fixed the permissions.

Comment: no, i have for all directories 770 and for files 600 and i have a 403 Forbidden error, with nobody user i can;t access files with a cPanel ftp user

Comment: OK, so you still have some sort of file permission problem.  Perhaps you should read up on that: https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions